# Need help with boot repair tool: After installing Ubuntu along side w Win7, wont boot, ran bootRepair tool, how do i make BIOS boot on sdc?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

So I previously posted the initial part of the problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/667783/grub-rescue-prompt-booted-from-live-usb-missing-config-file-in-grub-dir-bootr

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 along side Windows 7 pro. When I booted my machine I was greeted with the grub rescue prompt. I tried setting the root and prefix to the appropriate partitions as suggested on this site and still get grub rescue>. I also tried reinstalling grub in the chroot environment and got a error asking if the device was mounted and it was. I ran the boot repair tool and these are the results:

```
Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12297362/


In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdc (80.0GB) disk!
```

The last statement is where I am stuck. In the bios boot options `sdc` is not listed. The only options are hardrive, cdrom, usb and network. None of these options have submenus.  When I choose hard-drive I have the same problem.

How do I make the BIOS boot on `sdc`?

Comment: Isn't  the `sdc` your harddrive?

Comment: @Ron well it's part of it, I have windows on sda and swap I think on sdb

Comment: Yeah I've done that with the same results.

Comment: @Ron is there a way to boot specifically to sdc? And if not why is the boot repair tool so specific?